# How do I merge two tables in single database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have two table say `table1` and `table2` both tables have same structure but pk index values are different. so repetation is minimum.

```
table1 has got 56000 datas

table2 has got 23000 datas
```

I want merge/import `table2` to `table1.` there may be some repetations in PK so I need to ignore that data(dont want to import/rewrite or duplicate) and import rest of the data. I am using phpmyadmin so I want do it through that.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you can do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

to ignore duplicate keys.

However, please try it on a third table first ;)

Here's a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: excellent answer.  I used this to export a table from one database and import it to another and just use this line to merge the two without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UNION DISTINCT` into another table?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

So you could write something like this:

```
insert into table3
select * from table1 
union distinct 
select * from table2
```

Hope that helps.

Sorry if syntax is not spot on - don't use MySQL here in work.